# Android crash on react-native-webrtc addIceCandidates

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-webrtc

I'm trying to stream live video from a remote webcam but it crashes on Android when I try to add the ice candidates to the peerConnection. This same code works on ios and I believe have followed the Android setup correctly.
I read somewhere that I need to make sure the answer is created before adding ice candidates so I have created an array and now wait for the answer to be created and local description set but that didn't help my problem. I wonder if it has to do with the proper format of the candidate?

Here is how I'm adding ice candidates

```
    try {
      peerConnection.addIceCandidate(candidate).catch(e => {
        console.log(`Failure during addIceCandidate(): ${e.name}`) //this never logs
      })
      console.log('added ice candidate')
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Failed to add remote ICE candidate', err)
    }
```

This is the format of candidate:

```
{"candidate": "candidate:1 1 UDP 2013266431 fe80::e446:fbff:fe30:d913 53393 typ host", "sdpMLineIndex": 0, "sdpMid": undefined}
```

I have commented out almost everything else from this code so I believe the addIceCandidate is my problem, plus I see this in the backtrace of the crash:

```
      #09 pc 00000000000412c0  [anon:dalvik-classes10.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~XBCQ7AoUnEeLqIu8zNssPA==/com.myappname-_s6oKL5s7auBSrV7jp3f9g==/base.apk!classes10.dex] (org.webrtc.PeerConnection.addIceCandidate+12)
```

I see this in the Hermes log:

16:22:25.900
2832
System.err
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'byte[] java.lang.String.getBytes(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
16:22:25.907
2832
System.err
at org.webrtc.JniHelper.getStringBytes(JniHelper.java:25)
16:22:25.907
2832
System.err
at org.webrtc.PeerConnection.nativeAddIceCandidate(Native Method)
16:22:25.907
2832
System.err
at org.webrtc.PeerConnection.addIceCandidate(PeerConnection.java:896)
16:22:25.907
2832
System.err
at com.oney.WebRTCModule.WebRTCModule.peerConnectionAddICECandidateAsync(WebRTCModule.java:877)
16:22:25.907
2832
System.err
at com.oney.WebRTCModule.WebRTCModule.lambda$peerConnectionAddICECandidate$18$com-oney-WebRTCModule-WebRTCModule(WebRTCModule.java:862)
16:22:25.907
2832
System.err
at com.oney.WebRTCModule.WebRTCModule$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.run(Unknown Source:8)
16:22:25.907
2832
System.err
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
16:22:25.907
2832
System.err
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
16:22:25.907
2832
System.err
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

Do I need to convert the candidate to JSON or string? Is there something else I can do to find out more about the specific error?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by adding a sdpMid to the candidates before using them. I noticed that the sdp response had a property called sdpMid = 'video0' so I added that and it started working. I'm not sure why this wasn't a problem on ios but I had seen in the documentation that you could get a type error if both the sdpMid and sdpMLineIndex were null so I decided to give it a shot and it worked. Hope it helps someone else.